# How do I update the react component when i click the search button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and javascript and am playing around accessing a public api. I have the following function:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CountrySWR from "./CountrySWR";


export default function SearchForm(){
    const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState("a");

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const query = e.target("query");
        setCountryName(query);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input name="query"/>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <CountrySWR name={countryName}/>
        </>
    );
};
```

and the **CountrySWR.js** looks like:

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useState } from "react";


const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

export default function CountrySWR({name}){

    const url = "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/" + name;

    const {
        data : countries,
        error,
        isLoading,
    } = useSWR(url, fetcher);


    if(error) return <div className="failure">Failed to load data</div>;
    if(isLoading) return <div className="loading">Loading, please wait...</div>

    if(length > 1){
        txt = 'Territories in ' + name;
    }


    return(
        <div style={{ columnns: "150px 6", padding: "10px", margin: '20px', width: 'fit-content'}}>
            <h2>{txt}</h2>
            {countries &&
                countries.map((country, index) => (
                    <div key={index} style={{margin: '20px', border:"1px solid gray", padding: '20px',
                    borderRadius: '10px', display: 'inline-block'}}>
                        <h4>{country.name.common}</h4>
                        <p>Population: {country.population.toLocaleString('en-US')}</p>
                        {country.name.special !==  null ? <p>{country.name.special}</p> : <p>{country.name}</p>}

                        <img key={index} src={country.flags.png} 
                                alt="flag" height={150}
                                style={{margin: '10px',border: '1px solid gray'}}/>
                        
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    );

}
```

I am calling like this in App.js:

```
<>
...
  <SearchForm />
</>
```

The page loads initially ok with a list of CountrySWG elements, then when I click the Search button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.target is not a function
    at handleSubmit (SearchForm.js:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1).....
```

What do I need to do to fix this so that the <CountrySWG updates when I press the Search button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a small mistake in your code. The e.target should be called with the argument being the name or id of the form element you want to target, not the string "query". Additionally, you should use e.target.value to get the value of the input field. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```js
 const handleSubmit = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // in here query is a id of input which located in form
      console.log(e.target.query.value)
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input id='query' type="text" />
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to control the input with a state variable.

```
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(''); // Declare a state variable...
  // ...
  return (
    <input
      value={query} // ...force the input's value to match the state variable...
      onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} // ... and update the state variable on any edits
    />
  );
```

In such a case you can update country state to match query on submission.

```
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCountryName(query);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your query and write

`const query = e.target.value`
instead of `const query = e.target("query")`;

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the **handleSubmit** function to:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const query = e.target.query.value;        
        setCountryName(query);

    }
```

and I am now getting the result I expected.